# Choosing best suited classifier algorithm

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, classification, text-classification

How to choose/determine classifier for the given data set?

As input training data given. How to know which classifier will be best choice and give most accurate result? Is there any cases when Bayes classification is better than kNN or any other classification algorithm.

Comment: what results are you hoping to get? What is the data you are hoping to mine? This will hugely influence your choice of classifier. Based on my understanding, you have the TF-IDF which basically extract important part of the description of your product. The second file, what do you mean by the description? is it a line of String or is it a numerical descriptor (i.e. Covariance & Mean).

Comment: The usual way to decide which is best is to use them all, and measure results against a holdout test set. Choose the measurement criteria based on your intended use of the classifier (e.g. are mistakes in classification easy to fix?) You may, with experience, get a feel for likely good performing classifiers. If you have time, and for you best means "most accurate at any cost" then probably the best will be an ensemble of multiple different classifiers.

Comment: there are cases where Bayesian Classification will perform better than K-Nearest Neighbour, especially when the data features are very sparse (i.e. they don't overlap), an example would be Age vs what school you are attending, but do not expect it to perform a lot better, its main advantage is speed

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should always evaluate your algorithms with [cross validation.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_%28statistics%29) For that you split your data into training and validation sets, train your classifiers with the first group and use the latter to get an approximate error of your classifier.

That said, usually you'll end up testing different classifiers and algorithms. There is no way to tell for sure which method is going to work how well. Of course if you have more insight on the meaning behind your data, it will make things easier. You might split classification into different stages or modify your algorithm in some ways to suit the problem better. Basically everything is allowed and if for instance your values are scattered over the range of 0-100, but most are either in the range 0-10 or 90-100, you might want to check if it makes sense to make a first decision (like a decision stump) where you check if  `0=<x<=50` or `100>=x>50` and then use different classifiers for the two groups.

It is simply not possible to give a general advice to an arbitrary problem. The "best" choice really depends on the very specific nature of your data.

Same goes for the Kernels for some of the Classifiers. If you know anything about the nature of the data, you might be able to create a custom kernel function tailored for your problem.

The algorithms you mentioned and others like SVM or adaboost differ in a lot of things. Some classifiers are cheap to train but cost more to evaluate (kNN) while others are expensive to train, but very cheap to evaluate.

Like I said, you'll probably end up testing a lot of things. Just make sure you use **cross validation** to get an estimate of your classifier's performance. It's not enough to only look at the classification error during training.